# twin.macro jest test (tw is not defined)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, vite

When testing react component using jest that is styled with tw.div`` pattern i get an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'div')". I'm using vite + react + typscript + tailwind + twin.macro

```
// MyCustomComponent.tsx

import tw from 'twin.macro';

const Container = tw.div`relative w-full`;

export const MyCustomComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      ...
    </Container>)
}
```

```
// MyCustomComponent.test.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MyCustomComponent } from '../MyCustomComponent';

describe('MyCustomComponent...', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    render(< MyCustomComponent />);
    ...
  });
});
```

I tried with [this](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/issues/565) solution but didn't work for me.